# How to solve simple equation with random variables?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

1. Let $X$, $A$, $B$ be random variables with values over $\mathbb{N}$
2. All variables may have a different distribution
3. $A$ and $X$ are independent
4. $B$ verifies $B = X + A$

Knowing the distributions of $A$ and $B$, can I solve for $X$? Ideally I am looking for an algorithm to sample from $A$ and $B$ and generate values following the distribution of $X$.

Is there a way to combine values sampled from $A$ and $B$ to get a value with the distribution of $X$?

---

Here is an example:

- $A$ has the distribution $P(A = 0) = {{1} \over {2}}$, $P(A = 1) = {{1} \over {2}}$ (coin flip with values 0 and 1)
- $B$ has the distribution $P(B = 0) = {{1} \over {4}}$, $P(B = 1) = {{1} \over {2}}$, $P(B = 2) = {{1} \over {4}}$ (sum of two coin flips with values 0 and 1)

It's fairly easy to deduce that the solution $X$ with $P(X = 0) = {{1} \over {2}}$, $P(X = 1) = {{1} \over {2}}$ (coin flip with values 0 and 1) works. But it's not clear for me how to derive it more generally.

---

The trivial solution $X = B - A$ does not work with independent sampling as it could create a situation where $X = -1$ (if $B = 0$ and $A = 1$). This means that the formula should be different or that sampling from $A$ and $B$ can't be independent.

---

When searching on the internet how to solve equations involving random variables, I found this math.stackexchange link ["Solving" equations in random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4877700/solving-equations-in-random-variables), unfortunately it is deleted and I only have this small excerpt from Google:
[image]

Comment: Use the power generating function $p_X(s) := \mathbb{E} s^X, 0 \leq s \leq 1$. Then $p_B(s) = p_X(s) \cdot p_A(s)$ and from this you get the p.g.f. $p_X(s) = p_B(s)/p_A(s)$. Using standard techniques from probability theory you get the distribution of $X$. Unfortunately this is no method to simulate $X$.

Comment: Sorry, power generating function should be replaced by probability generating function.

Comment: If you want to simulate you get a sequence $(a_n,b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and from this $(x_n) = (b_n,a_n)$. If your model is correct we must have $a_n \leq b_n$ always!